# Why do all the variants of SHA256 appear as SHA256Managed?

Tags: c#, hash, md5, checksum, sha256

I'm writing an extension method that simplifies the creation of hashes by removing a ton of boilerplate, my problem is however that whenever I step through the code, I can see that it **always** picks `SHA256Managed`, regardless of whether or not I call `SHA256.Create()`, `SHA256Cng.Create()`, `SHA256Managed.Create()` or `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create()`

It's the same story when I pick a different hashing algorithm like MD5, but in the case of MD5 it *always* picks `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` regardless of class that I actually use...

Why is that?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Utility.Methods
{
    public enum HashType { MD5, SHA512, SHA256, SHA384, SHA1 }
    public enum HashSubType {Normal, Cng, Managed, CryptoServiceProvider}

    public static class TextHasher
    {
        public static string Hash(this string input, HashType hash, HashSubType subType = HashSubType.Normal)
        {
            Func<HashAlgorithm, string> hashFunction = alg => HashingHelper(input, alg);

            switch (subType)
            {
                case HashSubType.Normal:
                    return hashFunction(NormalHashes(hash));
                case HashSubType.Cng:
                    return hashFunction(CngHashes(hash));
                case HashSubType.Managed:
                    return hashFunction(ManagedHashes(hash));
                case HashSubType.CryptoServiceProvider:
                    return hashFunction(CSPHashes(hash));
                default: return "error"; // unreachable
            }
        }

        private static string HashingHelper(string text, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
        {
            Func<string, byte[]> getHash = input => algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            Array.ForEach(getHash(text), b => sb.Append(b.ToString("X")));

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private static HashAlgorithm NormalHashes(HashType hash)
        {
            switch (hash)
            {
                case HashType.MD5:
                    return MD5.Create();
                case HashType.SHA1:
                    return SHA1.Create();
                case HashType.SHA256:
                    return SHA256.Create();
                case HashType.SHA384:
                    return SHA384.Create();
                case HashType.SHA512:
                    return SHA512.Create();
                default: return null; // unreachable
            }
        }

        private static HashAlgorithm CngHashes(HashType hash)
        {
            switch (hash)
            {
                case HashType.MD5:
                    return MD5Cng.Create();
                case HashType.SHA1:
                    return SHA1Cng.Create();
                case HashType.SHA256:
                    return SHA256Cng.Create();
                case HashType.SHA384:
                    return SHA384Cng.Create();
                case HashType.SHA512:
                    return SHA512Cng.Create();
                default: return null; // unreachable
            }
        }

        private static HashAlgorithm ManagedHashes(HashType hash)
        {
            switch (hash)
            {
                case HashType.SHA1:
                    return SHA1Managed.Create();
                case HashType.SHA256:
                    return SHA256Managed.Create();
                case HashType.SHA384:
                    return SHA384Managed.Create();
                case HashType.SHA512:
                    return SHA512Managed.Create();
                default: return null; // unreachable
            }
        }

        private static HashAlgorithm CSPHashes(HashType hash)
        {
            switch (hash)
            {
                case HashType.MD5:
                    return MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
                case HashType.SHA1:
                    return SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
                case HashType.SHA256:
                    return SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
                case HashType.SHA384:
                    return SHA384CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
                case HashType.SHA512:
                    return SHA512CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
                default: return null; // unreachable
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, any help?

Comment: It's not especially surprising (but I'd have thought it should be generating warnings) since `Create` is statically defined on the `SHA256` class, and the other classes inherit from that, and so you're calling the same method in each case. The non-abstract classes have public constructors.

Comment: so what's the point of having other versions of the class if the create method doesn't change what it's doing?

Comment: Because the instances of those classes do different things. They just aren't relevant for your use case.

Comment: 1) You can directly *construct* other versions of the class if that's what you want to obtain, 2) You can use the overload of `Create` that accepts a string to choose a non-default, and 3) Which class to construct if you use this overload is configured at the machine level and not hard coded.

Comment: that's not exactly helpful if the doc doesn't specify what strings are legal to use... I could essentially do `SHA256.Create("Dog");`

Comment: You can. Just updated my answer with the way to do `HashAlgorithm.Create("Dog")`

Comment: If you're in a position where `SHA256Managed.Create();` compiled, you were already going around the houses by not just writing `new SHA256Managed();`. The other options are for when you don't (at compile time) know exactly which class you want to create an instance of.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because you are always calling the same static method, [SHA256.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z08hz7ad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). SHA256 is an abstract class and its descendants do *not* provide an alternate method. In fact, Resharper will give you a warning that you are accessing a static member from a derived type.

In fact, calling SHA256.Create is the same as calling [HashAlgorithm.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wet69s13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Both classes call the same implementation internally and simply cast the result to different types.

The [SHA256.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z08hz7ad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will create the default implementation that is specified in machine.config and can be overriden in your app.config

If you want to use a specific provider, use [SHA256.Create(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0zc58zh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) passing the name of the provider you want to use.

Examples are:

```
SHA256.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng");
HashAlgorithm.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng");
SHA256.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider");
```

**EDIT**

The documentation of [HashAlgorithm.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wet69s13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifies a list of valid algorithm names. The MSDN article [Mapping Algorithm Names to Cryptography Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/693aff9y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes how you can map algorithm names to other providers (your own, third-party, hardware-accelerated or whatever) and use them instead of the default algorithms.

**EDIT 2**

It is also possible to change the mappings programmatically. So, to map "Dog" to the SHA512CryptoServiceProvider, you just need to write:

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(
             typeof(System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider),
             "Dog");
var t4 = HashAlgorithm.Create("Dog");
```

Comment: but I don't use sha256.create every time... I use sha256Managed.create and sha256Cng.create for the others, and it still gives me the same result...

Comment: @ElectricCoffee - there is no `sha256Managed.Create` method - but `sha256Managed` *inherits* from `Sha256` and so the call can be compiled.

Comment: The point of what? You are calling a static method the wrong way. If you want to create different implementations, just use Create(string) with the name of the provider

Comment: yeah thanks, it'd help if I knew what the string should contain, because the documentation doesn't tell me this... You know what? I'm gonna make a `SHA256.Create("Dog");`

Comment: Just use the type names. I added some examples

Comment: I seriously don't understand why microsoft didn't just have the class names go there instead of strings

Comment: That's what they did. These are the class names. You can also define more entries, install third-party providers that will have to be identified in a transparent way

Comment: Then how would you use third-party providers or new OS implementations without recompiling?

Comment: make it easy to extend the class?